# How to execute a .py script from C if Python is embedded?

Tags: python, c

I can't find relevant information about this. For lua, if you want to execute a test.lua file from the main() C function, you call `lua_dofile("test.lua")`. 
What is the python equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are embedding Python, use [`PyRun_SimpleFile`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/veryhigh.html#PyRun_SimpleFile):

```
FILE *fp = fopen("test.py", "r");
int ret = PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, "test.py");
if(ret < 0) {
    /* exception occurred */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the manual page for [exec](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) - there are a variety of options to execute a program/script. [System](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) could also be an alternative.